# How to avoid overfitting in training data?

Tags: machine-learning

I am a project in Bioinformatics where I have large training data set. It consists of around 18,000 positive and 1000 Negative instances. If I use this data as a training set then Positive instances will completely dominate over negative instances. So, during classification of test data, my negative data are also misclassified as positive.

Is there any simple way to make a balance set of these positive and negative data to over come this problem?

Comment: Interesting question. I did a quick search and found this, hope it helps: http://florianhartl.com/thoughts-on-machine-learning-dealing-with-skewed-classes.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics. Perhaps it should be asked on crossvalidated.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin It's not about statistics. It's about machine learning as the tag clearly suggests. Over-fitting is also a major concern in this domain. I agree that it this form it's not very suitable for SO though.

Comment: sorry guys, I have made my query more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Very broad question, but in general you can roughly distinguish the following methods to deal with over-fitting:

- [regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)) (particular type depending on your approximator/classifier)
- [early stopping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_stopping) (based on the validation set)
- [cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) (to select the model that has the best generalization most likely)

In case of unbalanced training examples ensembles of one vs. all classifiers have been reported to yield good results (e.g. [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6643980)). You can also use sampling techniques (lots of various propositions can be found via google).

Comment: Is 'early stoping' subset of the regularization?

Comment: @jong-hyunYeo Yeah, seems so. Intuitively it somehow falls into a separate category because you can use it always in the same way regardless of the details of the model you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can try "class weight" approach in which the smaller class gets more weight, thus taking more cost to mis-classify the negative labelled class.

Besides, if you are using the logistic classifier, you can tune the threshold of positive/negative prediction, and observe the change of [precision and recall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall), then make a trade-off between them by [F-measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score) using cross validation data.

Yet I would say that using a very large training set makes it unlikely for model to overfit the training data.

Comment: Hi thanks, I have modified my problem making more specific. I am using weka based on SVM for classification problem. I cant assign calss weight approach I think, I need to find the way to make the dataset balanced beteen positive and negative.